# twisted clientConnectionLost catch/suppress Exception

Tags: python, exception, twisted

I have a project that uses twisted. In a child class from twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory, there are methods for clientConnectionLost / clientConnectionFailed. When an error occurs in the data exchange, this method execution with connector and reason. I can look at the type and value of exception. But I did not find information on how to suppress it. After processing, it is raise up as Unhandled Error. And I can not make a global exception handler, I need to handle exceptions depending on the type and value in this context(and re-connect etc).

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        raise Exception('Connect error')


class Client(ClientFactory):
    protocol = MyProtocol

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print reason.type, reason.value  # show type and message, OK
        reason.cleanFailure()  # ???


reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 80, Client())
reactor.run()

# Unhandled Error
# Traceback (most recent call last): ...............
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://sscce.org/

Comment: You really dont understand this code or just want to look a smarty? OK, Im written self-contained example.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear before.  Your edits appear to have clarified it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        raise Exception('Connect error')
```

is basically broken.  The reactor does you a favor and logs the exception for you (it *would* be pretty terrible if it didn't at least do that).  You can "handle" this exception by way of the logging system but the reactor does not give you any other facilities for handling it.

This is because raising an exception from `connectionMade` is a violation of the protocol interface.

The solution is to handle the exception inside `connectionMade` (or `dataReceived` or any of the other protocol methods you might be using).  For example:

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        try:
            raise Exception('Connect error')
        except ...:
            ...
```

Note that `cleanFailure` doesn't do anything related to what you want here.  It just scrapes some references out of the `Failure` to make garbage collection proceed more easily.